# why is my certificate expiring so soon?

Tags: jetty, ssl-certificate

I created a keystore for Artifactory as follows:

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out jetty.key
openssl req -new -x509 -key jetty.key -out jetty.crt
keytool -keystore keystore -import -alias jetty -file jetty.crt -trustcacerts
openssl req -new -key jetty.key -out jetty.csr
openssl pkcs12 -inkey jetty.key -in jetty.crt -export -out jetty.pkcs12
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore jetty.pkcs12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore keystore
```

I just created it this week but am already getting a warning that the certificate is expiring soon.

```
"WARNING - Certificate expires in 26 day(s) ".
```

why is it expiring so soon and how can I extend the expiry date?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `-days 360` to the `openssl req` command. From the [manual](https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/req.html):

```
-days n
  when the -x509 option is being used this specifies the number of
  days to certify the certificate for. The default is 30 days.
```

You can also [use keytool directly without openssl](http://www.sslshopper.com/article-how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate-using-java-keytool.html). The according parameter is named `-validity` there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It helped me. I can award the bounty only after 5 more hours. I will do it as soon as that happens.